# Kotlin-Android studio 3.6.1 Gradle 5.6.4 Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, gradle, junit4

Andoid-Studio-3.6.1 - Kotlin- am trying to do some tests for my application but this Error aquire and i cant fix it (am new at Android developement)
Error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugUnitTestCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Comment: Looks like your JUnit 5 dependencies are not working in your project. Can you please add Logcat and build.gradle for app. thnaks.